# Debian: install newest (newer than default) version of single package (but don't break when default catches up)

Tags: debian, python, apt, debian-bullseye

I'm using debian bullseye.

I want to install a newer version than default for a single package: `python3`.
I do not want this behaviour for *all* packages.

Also I do not want to install from a tar ball, since this won't work with `apt update`. Also I want this to not interfere with the package repository (still receive updates from there).

Comment: Why don't you checkout the source and build it if you want a newer version than supplied by your OS?

Comment: I have a feeling that we're not talking about a single package here. If it were so, I'd suggest looking at backports and, if this doesn't help, get the source from sid and build. But for getting a newer Python version, I'd recommend something like `pyenv`.

Answer (score 1):

This type of scenario is handled by 'APT Pinning', as described on [the Debian Wiki page for apt configuration](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration#apt_preferences_.28APT_pinning.29).

You will need to be very careful with version dependencies, though. I suspect that upgrading `python3` will involve upgrading so many dependent packages that you'll encounter version conflicts with packages required elsewhere in your system.